Running Behave in parallel in Jenkins with isolated contexts
I'm trying to run a behave script with Allure which executes two features to run in parallel that works fine locally. When executing with Jenkins inside a Docker container the contexts are shared between executions and I don't understand why and how to debug. A screenshot shows the same context is being used when doing the search.
from threading import Thread
import subprocess
import os
import shutil

def run_feature(feature):
    try:
        # Unique report for each feature
        report_base = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(feature))[0]
        output_dir = f"reports/{report_base}"
        if os.path.exists(output_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(output_dir)
            print(f"Deleted existing directory: {output_dir}")

        os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
        subprocess.run(
            [
                "behave",
                feature,
                "--format", "pretty", "--outfile", f"{output_dir}/{report_base}_pretty.txt",
                "--format", "json", "--outfile", f"reports/json_reports/{report_base}.json",
                "--format", "allure_behave.formatter:AllureFormatter", "--outfile", "allure-results",
                "--junit", "--junit-directory", f"{report_base}_junit.xml", "--no-capture"
            ], 
            check=True, 
            timeout=45,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(f"Error running {feature}: {e}")
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as e:
        print(f"Timeout running {feature}: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    feature_dir = "features/features/"
    features = [os.path.join(feature_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(feature_dir) if f.endswith(".feature")]
    
    for directory in ["reports/json_reports", "allure-results", "screenshots"]:
        if os.path.exists(directory):
            shutil.rmtree(directory)
            print(f"Deleted existing directory: {directory}")
        os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)

    threads = []
    for feature in features:
        # run_feature(feature)
        thread = Thread(target=run_feature, args=(feature,))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


Since it's in jenkins it needs to run in headless mode and my environments.py is:
from behave import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import allure

def before_all(context):
    print("Test execution started!")

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # Enables debugging port
    options.add_argument("--log-level=0")  # Ensure logging is not suppressed
    options.add_argument("--headless")  # Headless mode for Jenkins
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # To run without sandboxing
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # To fix shared memory issues

    try:
        # Automatically fetch and set up the appropriate version of ChromeDriver
        context.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
            options=options
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error initializing WebDriver: {e}")
        raise
    # context.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    context.driver.maximize_window()
    print(f"Starting: {scenario.name}")

def after_scenario(context, scenario):
    print(f"Finished: {scenario.name}")
    context.driver.quit()
    
def before_step(context, step):
    print(f"{step.name}")
    context.screenshot_path = None
    context.screenshot_name = None

def after_step(context, step):
    print(f"{step.name}")
    if step.status == "failed":
        screenshot_path = getattr(context, "screenshot_path", None)
        screenshot_name = getattr(context, "screenshot_name", None)
        if screenshot_path is not None:
            context.driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)
            with open(screenshot_path, 'rb') as file:
                allure.attach(file.read(), name=screenshot_name, attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)

Steps:
from behave import given, when, then
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

@given('I am on the Google search page')
def step_given_i_am_on_the_google_search_page(context):
    context.driver.get("https://www.google.com")

@when('I search for "{keyword}"')
def step_when_i_search_for_keyword(context, keyword):
    search_box = context.driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
    search_box.send_keys(keyword)
    search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    context.screenshot_name = f"{keyword} Search Screenshot"
    context.screenshot_path = f'screenshots/{keyword}_screenshot_{int(time.time())}.png'
    WebDriverWait(context.driver, 20).until(
        EC.title_contains(f"{keyword}")
    )

@then('the "{keyword}" search results should be displayed')
def step_then_the_search_results_should_be_displayed(context, keyword):
    context.screenshot_name = f"{keyword} Search Screenshot"
    context.screenshot_path = f'screenshots/{keyword}_screenshot_{int(time.time())}.png'
    actual_title = context.driver.title
    assert f"{keyword}" in actual_title, (
        f"Expected Contains: {keyword} \n"
        f"Actual: {actual_title}"
    )

Features:
Feature: Google Search

  Scenario: Search for keyword 1
    Given I am on the Google search page
    When I search for "Behave BDD"
    Then the "Behave BDD" search results should be displayed

Feature: Google Search

  Scenario: Search for keyword 2
    Given I am on the Google search page
    When I search for "Behave BDD Python"
    Then the "Behave BDD Pythonadfg" search results should be displayed

Sample image:
Shared Context Step
I'm aware that there is the behave-parallel library and was wondering if it's still useful as it doesn't look maintained.
The main build step in jenkins is just this:
if [ ! -d "venv" ]; then
  python3 -m venv venv
fi

. venv/bin/activate

pip install --upgrade pip
pip install behave
pip install selenium
pip install allure-behave
pip install webdriver-manager
python3 run_tests.py

deactivate

Running it sequentially is fine but not when multithreaded. I allocated some shared memory for this container to start with docker run --shm-size=2g my-selenium-test-container  but don't know much about any of this configuration.
